# GROUPBY and ORDERBY only produce 1 result per group?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I'm trying to get my result in groups and ordered but it seems I only get one result per group, why is this? How can I get the entire groups and those ordered?

```
$group = "TODO_PRIO";
$get_groups = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TODOS WHERE TODO_USER LIKE '%,$currentuser,%' 
GROUP BY $group");

while($arrayz = mysql_fetch_array($get_groups)){
echo $arrayz['TODO_PRIO']."</br>";
}
```

The above code outputs the following and is only showing one of each group.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

A little more explanation:
I want to get all my results into clusters so I can choose to get them into clusters where they match date or priority or reference, then I want to get those clusters and organize them by other things. For instance I want to cluster by priority and then order each cluster by date or reference.

First I was trying to do this by getting it all from an array and clustering sub arrays, which works, but then the ordering each subarray was not working and this seemed like a better more simple solution.

Comment: Please post the sample data from this table `TODOS` with the desired output.

Comment: Group By groups the results by the grouped column. This therefor is expected behavior.. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you expecting GROUP to do? If you want to just make it so all the 1's appear together, then all the 2's etc, just use an ORDER BY, if you need to calculate some information such as average, sum etc over a group of items then use GROUP BY

Comment: do not tell that group by is wrong..because it nature that group by only return first matching record..

Comment: By the way, you might want to consider putting the users for each TODO in a separate table. Your current approach does not conform to [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and `LIKE '%...'` will be slow for a large data set.

Comment: I expect the query to cluster my results into groups, which then can be ordered per group by say date or other value.

Comment: use `GROUP_CONCAT(expr)` – This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group.

Comment: This works but now I have a string with values but this doesn't allow me to show the entire record of each row that was chosen like this. I want to be able to use all the records that are linked to the part that is grouped, that is why I think maybe group_concat is not right for this

Comment: What do you mean by "cluster"? If you mean you want them to come out in a particular order, then use `order by`. *The entire point of `group by` is that it only produces one row per group*.

Comment: *"First I was trying to do this by getting it all from an array and clustering sub arrays, which works, but then the ordering each subarray was not working and this seemed like a better more simple solution."* Based on this, I think you'll be *far* better off learning how to write SQL to do this rather than writing PHP to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Thats what GROUP BY does. It Groups multiple rows to one row.
[Read it here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).
You need to ORDER it

```
SELECT * FROM TODOS WHERE TODO_USER LIKE '%,$currentuser,%' ORDER BY $group ASC
```

Then yo get something like

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
4
4
[...]
```

Or you can smoothly group it in PHP

```
$tmp = array();
while($arrayz = mysql_fetch_array($get_groups)){
    $tmp[$arrayz['TODO_PRIO']][] = $arrayz; //extra [] pushes it in a new subarray
}
```

This will result in an easy to use array:

```
array(
    1 => array(ToDo1,ToDo4,ToDo2),
    2 => array(ToDo5,ToDo3,ToDo6),
    [...]
)
```

Example usage with [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
//itterate over the various ToDo-prioritys
foreach($tmp as $ToDo_Prio => $ToDo_List)
{
    echo "Priority $ToDo_Prio:<br/><ul>";
    //itterate over the various ToDo-elements
    foreach($ToDo_List as $ToDo_Item)
    {
        echo "<li>".$ToDo_Item[<desired column>]."</li>"; //replace <desired column> with your Coumnname you want to display.
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Keep in mind, that $ToDo_Item is an array that contains a row from your Table. So you need to specify a Columnname.